# How Pass a complete TextView Object to another activity (or Save it and Reuse later)

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an android app which is used to add text on image and do some editing. I have the main image editing activity (mainEditActivity) where I have my image, textview and editing panel. I can change the selected image in two ways

1. Select one from the gallery which used the following code

> ```
> pickGalleryBtn.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
>             Intent intent = new Intent();
>             intent.setType("image/*");
>             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
>         });
> ```

and on activity result

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mainEditActivity, ImageCropActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image.url", selectedImageUri.toString());
            mainEditActivity.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There was an error reading the file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

ImageCropActivity will start the MainEditActivity after cropping the image

2. The user can also download an image by going to another page, which will again go through ImageCropActivity and land on MainEditActivity.

My problem is when user is changing the image through any of the above ways, the preferences (such as, text size, position, color, font ..) set on the textview is getting lost as the MainEditActivity restarts.

Is there any way I can save the textView itself (not just the text) so the user will not lose the preferences. I have tried, passing data intent, sharedprefrences, savedinstancestate etc but they will only allow String or Serializable object (TextView is not serializable)

Comment: Based on what I have understood, I suggest you move the `TextView` to a floating window, using a `Service`. You can find several implementations on how to do that if you search.

Comment: Not sure I understood the issue. Your TextView if set via XML will have all of its "preferences" set. Font size, font color, where everything is located etc. You only need to save the content itself so once you return to that activity you simply refresh the view with the saved data. Am I missing something in this question?

Comment: @AlonMinski, Most of the preferences like color, font size etc are changed programmatically. The user can edit almost everything they can by using controls that are available in UI. So if I refresh the UI, all changes are lost and the basic XML remains.

Comment: Ohh I see. Then perhaps create a custom view that persists to DB or SharedPref any change that is done to it. And once it loads again, query for that information and rebuild the view accordingly? So for instance if the user used a certain control to preform a certain action, that action will be saved. You can even create your own specific proprietary design for this data structure. Might go hand in hand with an undo mechanism. Like a Queue<Actions> kind of thing.

Comment: @AlonMinski, Thanks for the suggestion. But that seems to be a lot of work. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @Tomin, What i understand from your question, you are using Image Crop Activity only for cropping images and all the editing is done on MainEditActivity itself. So Why don't you just start ImageCropActivity with "startActivityForResult" and in return get the cropped image from ImageCropActivity .

Comment: @Manish, Good point. But I have one more activity for downloading images. (Please check point 2). That activity lets user to enter a search term and allows them to choose an image from the list of images returned. Of Course it will also go through cropping before reaching MainEditActivity. I dont know how I can use "startActivityForResult" for two different operations

Comment: @Manish, Seems like utilizing requestCode, I can make this work. Let me try that way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747283/manish)

I realized that there is no need to pass/save TextView object. I can consider the MainEditActivity as a parent activity for all other activities where the control is passed to other activities, but not completely. Before I used to start the activity using `startActivity` method which causes to lose all the data in that activity. Now I have changed the way I am calling the activities using `startActivityForResult` so that I will set the necessary data from other activities in MaindEditActivity.

Comment: Always Welcome . Happy coding!!